# Cocoa / CoreGraphics / Quartz - borderless Quicktime X like window with rounded edges

Tags: cocoa, quartz-graphics, nswindow, nsopenglview

I am developing a document based application for Mac OS X. It's a kind of media player, but instead of playing audio or video files it is supposed to open text-files containing meta-data specifying OpenGL animations. I would like to mimic Apples QuickTime X window style. This means, i have to do all the window drawings myself, because Cocoa has no appropriate window style.

There is one thing which gives me headaches: The rounded corners usually to be found on Mac OS X windows. I tried using the borderless window mask and working some CGS magic - there are some private Apple headers which allow window shaping, but they are of course undocumented. I was able to cut rectangular holes in my windows edges, but i couldn't figure out how Apple achieves rounded corners.

Creating a transparent window and drawing the frame myself does not work, because an OpenGL viewport is always rectangular, and the only way to change it is to turn on NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOpacity for alpha transparency and using the stencil buffer or shaders to cut out the edges, which seems like a hell of a lot of overhead.

If i put an OpenGLView into a standard Cocoa window with titlebar, the bottom edges are rounded. It seems this is happening at the NSThemeFrame stage of the view hierarchy. Any ideas how this is done?

Comment: Why do you assume that going the `NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOpacity` route will cause performance issues? Seems perfectly reasonable to me. Never assume. Test and Profile.

Comment: @Rob Because i did some research before posting my question. Turns out there are others who would can't seem to get the rounded corners right. People already tried `NSOpenGLSurfaceOpacity`, and they reported a big drop in performance. But i guess i'm out of options.

Comment: @cargath just because other people post about their inability to get something to work doesn't make it the gospel truth, how do you know that there isn't something else they are doing that is wrong, how do you know that there aren't thousands of other people not having problems and just *not* posting about their successes? Like Rob said, test and profile yourself!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I did. Resizing gets extremely slow when creating textures for the stencil buffer to crop the corners. That's not surprising. Of course i could not redraw OpenGL while resizing, but that's not an ideal option either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Robs suggestion didn't work and no one else contributed to the discussion i settled on using the stencil buffer to crop the windows corners. I did this by creating a texture from the windows background and rendering it into the stencil buffer, discarding all transparent pixels. Looks fine, but is slow when resizing the window :/

Answer (score 1):

Use a layer-backed view, and do your drawing in the `CALayer` on an invisible window. Layers include automatic handling of rounded corners and borders.

---

Background for `CALayer` is in the [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514). To create a layer for `NSView`, you need to call `[view setWantsLayer:YES]`. You would create a `CAOpenGLLayer` and assign it to the view using `setLayer:`.

See [CALayerEssentials](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CALayerEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html) for sample code demonstrating how to use `CAOpenGLLayer` among other layer types.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I haven't used CALayers before, so this is new to me - would i subclass a CAOpenGLLayer oder request a backing layer for my NSOpenGLView subclass? I can't seem to find any examples or tutorials that address my needs.

Comment: All i can find about CAOpenGLLayer is people having problems with them ;) Speed issues, picture artifacts etc

Comment: Well, i created a new Xcode project for testing purposes. I subclassed NSWindow to make it invisible and subclassed CAOpenGLLayer to do some OpenGL drawings. I then used IB to setup a new window using my NSWindow subclass and attached an NSView to it. I requested my CAOpenGLLayer subclass in my AppController code for this NSView. And it works, i could get it to draw into my window. Only it doesn't have rounded edges.

Answer (score 1):

This is an analysis of what it takes to get rounded corners on <= 10.9. Note that from 10.10+ you have `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` and transparent titlebar properties which make things easy.

So let's say you want to recreate the QuickTime X window. You've got an OpenGL view where you've rendered some beautiful teapots, but that darn titlebar keeps getting in the way. You think it'd be an easy thing, but boy are you mistaken:

Issue 1) On pre-10.12-ish osx, opengl views are their own surface. If you ever looked at the description for NSOpenGLView, it has a curious line that it doesn't accept any subviews. If you try it, you'll find that an openglview basically clobbers everything. Effectively an opengl view is like its own mini window (it has its own surface) which is always "on top" of everything underneath. So this means that setting aside the rounded corners, you won't be able to let the system draw the menu icons on top of it, and handling them yourself is tedious and ugly (e.g. hover effects, etc.)

Now there are still 2 ways you can mix opengl but have titles on top. First is via use of layers. In fact if you set the root view to be layered back, then NSOpenGLView automatically becomes layer backed as well. And then everything just magically works: you get rounded corners, *and* can render your close buttons on top. Note that to do this you have to escape the content view and essentially insert your own view as the first child of `NSThemeFrame`. Because the stoplight icons will come after your inserted view in the sibling order, they will be composited on top of your view. And because things are layer backed, this actually works. An example is shown below:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>
#import <OpenGL/glu.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class FOTWindowFrame;

/**
 View responsible for title bar drawing.
 */
@interface FOTWindowTitle : NSView

@end

/**
 View acting as the window's frame and responsible for mouse tracking.
 */
@interface FOTWindowFrame : NSView

@end

/**
 NSWindow subclass to make auto hiding and showing a window's title bar (a la QuickTime X) easier.
 */
@interface FOTWindow : NSWindow

@property (nonatomic, strong) FOTWindowFrame *fullContentView;

/**
 Adds a subview that stays below the title bar.

 @warning All views in this window will get wantsLayer = YES.
 */
- (void)addSubviewBelowTitleBar:(NSView *)subview;

/**
 The alpha value the title bar view will be set to when it fades in.
 */
@property CGFloat titleBarFadeInAlphaValue;

/**
 The alpha value the title bar view will be set to when it fades out.
 */
@property CGFloat titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue;

/**
 Block used to specify custom drawing code for a window's title bar.
 @param drawsAsMainWindow Whether the window is in its main state.
 @param drawingRect The entire drawing area of the title bar.
 @param clippingPath Path with the shape of the window title bar's rounded corners (can be used to clip to).
 */
typedef void (^FOTWindowTitleBarDrawingBlock)(BOOL drawsAsMainWindow, NSRect drawingRect, NSBezierPath *clippingPath);

/**
 Specify custom title bar background drawing code. If none is specified, the standard OS X title bar background will be drawn.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) FOTWindowTitleBarDrawingBlock titleBarDrawingBlock;

/**
 Block used to specify custom drawing code for a window's title.
 @param drawsAsMainWindow Whether the window is in its main state.
 @param drawingRect The entire drawing area of the title bar.
 */
typedef void (^FOTWindowTitleDrawingBlock)(BOOL drawsAsMainWindow, NSRect titleBarRect);

/**
 Specify custom title text drawing code. If none is specified, the standard OS X-style window title will be drawn.
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) FOTWindowTitleDrawingBlock titleDrawingBlock;

@end


#define kTitleBarHeight 400.0

@implementation FOTWindowTitle

// Draws the title bar background and window title
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    FOTWindow* window = (FOTWindow*)self.window;
    
    CGFloat roundedRectangleCornerRadius = 4;
    NSRect roundedRectangleRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(self.frame), kTitleBarHeight);
    NSRect roundedRectangleInnerRect = NSInsetRect(roundedRectangleRect, roundedRectangleCornerRadius, roundedRectangleCornerRadius);
    NSBezierPath* clippingPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [clippingPath moveToPoint: NSMakePoint(NSMinX(roundedRectangleRect), NSMinY(roundedRectangleRect))];
    [clippingPath lineToPoint: NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(roundedRectangleRect), NSMinY(roundedRectangleRect))];
    [clippingPath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(roundedRectangleInnerRect), NSMaxY(roundedRectangleInnerRect)) radius: roundedRectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 0 endAngle: 90];
    [clippingPath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter: NSMakePoint(NSMinX(roundedRectangleInnerRect), NSMaxY(roundedRectangleInnerRect)) radius: roundedRectangleCornerRadius startAngle: 90 endAngle: 180];
    [clippingPath closePath];
    
    BOOL drawsAsMainWindow = (window.isMainWindow && [NSApplication sharedApplication].isActive);
    NSRect drawingRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(self.frame), kTitleBarHeight);
    
    if (window.titleBarDrawingBlock) {
        // Draw custom titlebar background
        window.titleBarDrawingBlock(drawsAsMainWindow, drawingRect, clippingPath);
    } else {
        // Draw default titlebar background
        NSGradient* gradient;
        if (drawsAsMainWindow) {
            gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.66 alpha:1.0] endingColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.9 alpha:1.0]];
        } else {
            gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.878 alpha:1.0] endingColor:[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.976 alpha:1.0]];
        }
        
        [gradient drawInBezierPath:clippingPath angle:90];
        
        // 1px line
        NSRect shadowRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(self.frame), 1);
        [[NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:(drawsAsMainWindow)? 0.408 : 0.655 alpha:1.0] set];
        NSRectFill(shadowRect);
    }
    
    if (window.titleDrawingBlock) {
        // Draw custom title
        window.titleDrawingBlock(drawsAsMainWindow, drawingRect);
    } else {
        // Draw default title
        
        // Rect
        NSRect textRect;
        if (window.representedURL) {
            textRect = NSMakeRect(20, -2, NSWidth(self.frame)-20, NSHeight(self.frame));
        } else {
            textRect = NSMakeRect(0, -2, NSWidth(self.frame), NSHeight(self.frame));
        }
        
        // Paragraph style
        NSMutableParagraphStyle* textStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle].mutableCopy;
        [textStyle setAlignment: NSCenterTextAlignment];
        
        // Shadow
        NSShadow* titleTextShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
        titleTextShadow.shadowBlurRadius = 0.0;
        titleTextShadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(0, -1);
        titleTextShadow.shadowColor = [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5];
        
        NSColor *textColor = [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:56.0/255.0 alpha:drawsAsMainWindow? 1.0 : 0.5];
        
        // Draw the title
        NSDictionary* textFontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [NSFont titleBarFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSRegularControlSize]],
                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
                                             NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: textStyle,
                                             NSShadowAttributeName: titleTextShadow};
        
        [window.title drawInRect: textRect withAttributes: textFontAttributes];
    }
}

@end

#pragma mark -

@interface FOTWindowFrame ()

@property (strong) FOTWindowTitle *titleBar;

@end

@implementation FOTWindowFrame

- (BOOL) mouseDownCanMoveWindow {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return YES;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect andContent:(NSView*)view
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    
    if (self) {
        view.frame = frameRect;
    
        _titleBar = view;
        [_titleBar setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewMinYMargin|NSViewMinXMargin];
//      [_titleBar setAlphaValue:0];
        [self addSubview:_titleBar];
    }
    
    return self;
}

- (void)updateTrackingAreas
{
    [super updateTrackingAreas];
    
    [self addTrackingArea:[[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.frame options:NSTrackingActiveAlways|NSTrackingInVisibleRect|NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited owner:self userInfo:nil]];
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    FOTWindow* window = (FOTWindow*)self.window;
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeInAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeInAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeInAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeInAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowFullScreenButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeInAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeInAlphaValue];
//  [_titleBar.animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeInAlphaValue];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    FOTWindow* window = (FOTWindow*)self.window;
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowFullScreenButton].animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
    [[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
//  [_titleBar.animator setAlphaValue:window.titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [self.window.backgroundColor set];
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeCopy);
}

@end

#pragma mark -

@implementation FOTWindow
{
    NSView *_originalThemeFrame;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) mouseDownCanMoveWindow {
    return YES;
}

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:aStyle backing:bufferingType defer:NO];
    
    if (self) {
        _titleBarFadeInAlphaValue = 1.0;
        _titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue = 0.0;
        
        _originalThemeFrame = [self.contentView superview];
        _originalThemeFrame.wantsLayer = YES;
    }
    
    return self;
}

-(void) setContent: (NSView *) view {
    
    _fullContentView = [[FOTWindowFrame alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame andContent:view];
//  _fullContentView.wantsLayer = YES;
    [_originalThemeFrame addSubview:_fullContentView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:_originalThemeFrame.subviews[0]];
    
    [[self standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] setAlphaValue:_titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
    [[self standardWindowButton:NSWindowZoomButton] setAlphaValue:_titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
    [[self standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton] setAlphaValue:_titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
    
    [_fullContentView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
    [_fullContentView setFrame:_originalThemeFrame.frame];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[self standardWindowButton:NSWindowFullScreenButton] setAlphaValue:_titleBarFadeOutAlphaValue];
}

- (void)becomeKeyWindow
{
    [super becomeKeyWindow];
    [_fullContentView.titleBar setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)resignKeyWindow
{
    [super resignKeyWindow];
    [_fullContentView.titleBar setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)becomeMainWindow
{
    [super becomeMainWindow];
    [_fullContentView.titleBar setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)resignMainWindow
{
    [super resignMainWindow];
    [_fullContentView.titleBar setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)aString
{
    [super setTitle:aString];
    
    [self.fullContentView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [_fullContentView.titleBar setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)setRepresentedURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    [super setRepresentedURL:url];
    
    //Match the document icon button to the alpha value of the close button (and the other buttons, essentially)
    [[self standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] setAlphaValue:[self standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton].alphaValue];
    
    [_fullContentView.titleBar setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)addSubviewBelowTitleBar:(NSView *)subview
{
    [_fullContentView addSubview:subview positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:_fullContentView.titleBar];
}

@end

/******* */
@interface MyOpenGLView : NSOpenGLView
@end

@implementation MyOpenGLView

- (BOOL) mouseDownCanMoveWindow {
    return YES;
}

+ (BOOL)canDrawOpenGL {
    return YES;
}

- (void)prepareOpenGL {
    // Set up OpenGL context and other properties
    [super prepareOpenGL];
    [[self openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glFinish();
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    
    static float i = 0.5;
    i += 0.01;
    glClearColor(0.0f, i, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Swap the buffers to display the rendered image
//  [[self openGLContext] flushBuffer];
    glFlush();
}

@end

int x = 0;
MyOpenGLView *glView;

CVReturn MyDisplayCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink,
    const CVTimeStamp *inTime,
    const CVTimeStamp *outTime,
    CVOptionFlags flagsIn,
    CVOptionFlags *flagsOut,
    void *displayLinkContext) {
        [glView prepareOpenGL];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
            printf("-------\n");
            CVTimeStamp out;
            CVDisplayLinkGetCurrentTime(displayLink, &out);
            printf("Bef: %llu\n", out.videoTime);
            [glView drawRect:NSZeroRect];
            CVDisplayLinkGetCurrentTime(displayLink, &out);
            printf("Aft: %llu\n", out.videoTime);
        }
        CVDisplayLinkStop(displayLink);
        return kCVReturnSuccess;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // Set up the application and window
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [app setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

        FOTWindow *window = [[FOTWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
            styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask
            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
            defer:NO];
//      [window setBackingType:NSBackingStoreBuffered]; // New backing store is type 3, unbuffered
        [window setShowsResizeIndicator:YES];
        
        // Create an NSOpenGLPixelFormat object with double buffering enabled
        NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[] = {
//          NSOpenGLPFATripleBuffer,
            NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
            0
        };
        NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attribs];
        
        // Create an NSOpenGLContext object with the pixel format
        NSOpenGLContext *glContext = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pixelFormat shareContext:nil];
        
        // Set the pixel format and context for the view
        glView = [[MyOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400) pixelFormat:pixelFormat];
        [glView setOpenGLContext:glContext];
    
//      window.contentView = glView;
        [window setContent: glView];
        window.movableByWindowBackground = YES;
//      [window setContentView: glView];
        
        // Optionally see what happens when using a CAOpenGLLayer instance
    
      [glView setWantsLayer: NO]; // wantsLayer is actually forced
//      [glView.layer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor].CGColor];
        
        
        // Set up the window and run the application
        
//      NSView* frameView = [[window contentView] superview];
//      [glView setFrame:[frameView bounds]];
//      [frameView addSubview:glView];



//      window.contentView = glView;
        [window makeFirstResponder:glView];
        [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    
        
        GLint a = 1;
        [glContext setValues:&a forParameter:NSOpenGLCPSwapInterval];
        
        CVDisplayLinkRef _link;
        CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay(CGMainDisplayID(),&_link);
        
        
        CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(_link, MyDisplayCallback, NULL);

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            printf("Starting\n");
            CVDisplayLinkStart(_link);

        });
        
        [app run];
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the downside of an nsopengllayer is of course that all rendering must be done in the drawRect method, unlike an openglview where you can take the context and draw to it willy nilly outside drawRect. If you must use a non layer-backed view, there still is a way. There is an obscure `NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOrder` property which apple says if set to `-1` "If the value is –1, the order is below the window'. This doesn't make much sense unless you consider what I mentioned before about opengl views being their own surface, like their own "window".  So really this is equivalent to putting one window below another. (Likely this is an artifact from before layer backed views existed so this was a clever hack to effectively give you 2 layers reusing compositor mechanism) Now to practically make use of this, the window on top (the window that *you* created), has to be transparent and allow content from below to poke through. So that's what you do: you must set opacity to NO, set a transparent background color, and draw a clear rect in your associated nsopenglview, to allow content from below to poke through. Combining all that with the `NSWindowFrame` trick from above you can achieve something similar of having close icons directly on top of your content, with rounded corners.

The downside of all this is that as you noted a non-opaque nswindow is really slow when resizing, which other people have noted (https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Nov/msg00004.html or https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2012/Feb/msg00667.html).  There's also another option, you could take the traditional nsopenglview (opaque window, on top surface) and create another transparent window on top of it that will house your controls. This transparent window is much smaller, only needing to be the titlebar size, so it should not suffer from the same performance penalty. You can see an example of this approach here: https://github.com/insidegui/GRGlassWindow

Now going back to the rounded corners:  If you actually run the above code for the transparent openglview you'll find that the bottom corners are rounded but top corners are not. This can be fixed by not drawing a full clear rect in the nsopenglview, but just drawing the rounded rect mask, which I'll leave as an exercise.

So to summarize, with a layer-backed view (in conjunction with the `NSThemeFrame` trick), you get top and bottom corners for free, with both OpenGL and regular quartz drawing.

With a non-layer backed view, bottom corners come "for free", and the top corners are in fact rounded as well but you need to take not to draw over them (unlike bottom corners, they don't seem to automatically clip). If you're using quartz drawing you need to mask out the corners when drawing. With an opaque nswindow and an "on top" gl surface, you have to create an opengl surface with transparency so that you don't paint over the corners. And with an "on bottom" gl surface you have to make the entire window transparent (non-opaque), and create the appropriate mask to let the content from below peek through.

But to me the really interesting thing is that the bottom corners are rounded *even if* you draw a non-layered opaque full-rect, meaning that somehow the rounded bottom corners are being automatically clipped/masked as needed, and this is not being done for the top corners. I tried really hard to trace how this happens, it seems as part of `NSThemeFrame` initialization it makes the following calls:

```
-[NSThemeFrame _maskCorners:clipRect:]
-[NSThemeFrame drawOverlayRect:] + 569
-[NSView _drawOverlayRectSet:] + 298
-[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 3138
-[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 841
-[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 314
-[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2828
-[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1680
```

where the signature is `- (void)_maskCorners:(NSUInteger)aFlags clipRect:(NSRect)aRect` and `aFlags` is a bitmask whose lower-two bits determine whether you want the bottom/top corners to be rounded. (rect here doesn't seem to matter, I've even replaced it with zero without changing the effect). You can even swizzle (or sublcass NSThemeFrame and override) this method yourself and see that if you set `_maskCorners` to `0` then the rounded bottom corners goes away. Normally this is only called with a value of `1` (bottom corner), but disassembly shows that it shold handled a value of `0b10` for top corner as well. So can we just swizzle this to always pass `0b11` and get rounded top *and* bottom corners?

I was really hopeful that it would work, but it seems we're out of luck and this doesn't work quite so easily. I even tried really hard to figure out exactly what's going on under the hood: internally `_maskCorners` calls into CoreUI framework `CUIRenderer::Draw`, which ends up calling `CUIArtFileRenderer::DrawWindowFrameStandard`. There are 4 specific CUI image ids: 0x4e79, 0x4e7b, 0x4e56, 0x4e58 which corespond to the image id masks for the 4 rounded corners. I was even able to extract the CGImageRef equivalent and indeed they are rounded corner masks (4e56 is for the left bottom corner, 4e58 is for right bottom corner). It takes these images and calls `CGContextSetCompositeOperation` then `CGContextDrawImages`. The code for all 4 corners is essentially identical though, so it's surprising that for some reason this simply doesn't seem to work for the top corners. Maybe the calculation for position is wrong and it's never noticed because it's never exercised, or maybe the window server itself is in on this conspiracy and the rounded bottom corners only work with its assistance (perhaps related to the "Apple headers which allow window shaping" you mentioned. If you recall what these were, I'd like to know.)

One thing to try if anyone is curious is to replicate what `DrawWindowFrameStandard` is doing by manually invoking CGContextDrawImage and seeing if you're able to mask out portions of the window. No idea how this actually interacts with opengl content though, although it seems like it must.

Comment: I finally solved it, see the second part of my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447645/nswindow-alternative-to-setopaqueno/78213126#78213126