# NSWindow: alternative to -setOpaque:NO

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nswindow, rounded-corners, private-methods

I want to have a window which is like QuickTime X window. An all opaque window with rounded corners.

I've obtained it implementing a custom borderless `NSWindow` with:

```
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setBackgroundColor: [NSColor clearColor]];
```

and a custom `NSView` with:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSBezierPath* thePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [thePath appendBezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect xRadius:radius yRadius:radius];
    [thePath fill];
}
```

It works as expected but the window becomes noticeably slow when it gets resized fast.

I've identified that this slowdown is given by `-setOpaque:NO`; if I remove that line, the window can be resized fast again but corners are obviously no more rounded.

Is there a way to avoid using `-setOpaque:NO` and still be able to have rounded corners? Maybe one can have a window which is all opaque except for the corners?

The view is a `NSOpenGLView` so I can leverage on OpenGL if it may helps.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416056/cocoa-coregraphics-quartz-borderless-quicktime-x-like-window-with-rounded

Answer (score 0):

See this Apple developer example: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: That example set window to transparent with -setOpaque:NO. I'm looking for a solution which lets me round window's corner without setting it transparent

Answer (score 0):

In Quartz/Core Graphics, opaque rects are faster to composite than non-opaque rects.
But an opaque window means you need to draw a rectangle and anything you didn't fill would be black.

If you want a custom window that is not a sharp-edged rectangle, you must set the window to be non-opaque.

Anyway, this is almost certainly, not your main bottleneck.

First thing is to stop doing so much stuff in drawRect:
Make that NSBezierPath a property.
Only replace it when the rect is actually changing size.
Only do that in viewWillDraw: or some earlier point.
Maybe one of the view or window resize NSNotifications or a delegate method.

In drawRect: you should do only drawing really, as much as possible.
You should only redraw what you need to, as much as possible.

This is still small, and probably not your bottleneck.
You'll need to examine the drawing in ALL of the views in your window.

Your window is really the root CGContext (drawing context) that you get access to on OS X. Everything in your context is all of your subviews.
Every subview is a potential drawing bottleneck.

An OpenGL view drawing during live resize of the window sounds like a prime candidate.
You might throttle frame rates or something during live resize of the view or the window.
That should get it a little snappier.

Beyond that, you'll notice from NSWindow and NSView classes that not drawing during live resize IS a performance win.

See the NSView Class documentation and specifically the methods noted under the section ***Managing Live Resize***

- inLiveResize
- preservesContentDuringLiveResize
- getRectsExposedDuringLiveResize:count:
- rectPreservedDuringLiveResize
- viewWillStartLiveResize
- viewDidEndLiveResize

Those last two look like a great place to sandwich some reduction in drawing,

Comment: Actually large non opaque rects are known to be notoriously slow to composite, this is seen especially during resize. Well they used to be anyway, it may not be an issue on modern macos

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally did enough reverse engineering of AppKit to figure out how to do this, particularly for the non-layer backed OpenGL view case which to my knowledge has not been done before. Obligatory note that all my analysis below is for < 10.10. Much of osx internals regarding window compositing and opengl has changed since then, and newer macOS exposes a public api for full-content transparent titlebar view anyway. But the analysis is of interest for those who are interested in inner workings of osx.

First please read the prelude to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416056/cocoa-coregraphics-quartz-borderless-quicktime-x-like-window-with-rounded/78209252#78209252) where I briefly discuss how opengl surfaces work on osx and what it takes to render content on top of them. By the end of that question, a solution for rounded corners was provided for the following cases:

- non-layer backed view drawn with quartz
- layer-backed openglview/quartz view
- non-layer backed openglview with transparent gl draw in an above-surface (this allows rounded rects but not on-top draw)
- non-layer backed openglview with non-transparent gl draw in a below-surface and non-opaque window

There was one final case I mused about at the end, non-layer backed views with everything opaque (this is the default most people talk about): in such a case, if you apply the `NSWindowFrame` trick to get a full-size content view, you get rounded bottom corners but you seem to always "draw over" the rounded top corners. So there must clearly be something special about the bottom corners, and this is what I'm going to discuss here.

When you create a titled NSWindow, what actually happens is that OSX uses private CGS api to create a special type of window which has non-opaque strips only on the top and bottom. In essence, this is a special type of window consisting of majority opaque but some non-opaque regions, and this is how the corners can be made without incurring the full-performance impact of having the entire window be transparent. This API is/was actually used in the Servo renderer as discussed [here](https://github.com/servo/glutin/pull/94) for similar performance benefits.

So now we get a rough idea of how corners with a traditional titled NSWindow are created: since they are actually transparent regions, NSThemeFrame just needs to apply the appropriate blend mask to let the background peek though. Since the bottom corner regions can overlap user content, NSThemeFrame seems to make sure to do the blending *after* your content NSView has drawn, so that the result is never covered up by anything else. This is not done for the top corners though (since normally user content never covers it) which explains the observed discrepancies.

Finally, you can actually control the size of the transparent regions by overriding (or swizzling) the `roundedCornerRadius` on `NSThemeFrame`.

The below example is a complete proof-of-concept showing that the bottom-left and top-right corners have a transparent region that can simply be drawn on at will, from the `drawRect` method of `NSThemeFrame`. It's important to note that if you try to get at it from your contentView, the drawing canvas doesn't seem to span the proper regions so it doesn't work. Trying to override `_maskCorners` (which is normally called after your content nsview is drawn and handles the bottom corner masking) to round the top-corners as well also doesn't work for a similar reason, it seems the drawing canvas there is fixed to only the bottom corner. But `NSThemeFrame`'s draw rect has access to the entire window and can freely draw on all of them.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#pragma mark AppKit



enum PrivateCGCompositeMode {
    kPrivateCGCompositeClear        = 0,
    kPrivateCGCompositeCopy     = 1,
    kPrivateCGCompositeSourceOver   = 2,
    kPrivateCGCompositeSourceIn     = 3,
    kPrivateCGCompositeSourceOut    = 4,
    kPrivateCGCompositeSourceAtop   = 5,
    kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationOver  = 6,
    kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationIn    = 7,
    kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationOut   = 8,
    kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationAtop  = 9,
    kPrivateCGCompositeXOR      = 10,
    kPrivateCGCompositePlusDarker   = 11, // (max (0, (1-d) + (1-s)))
    kPrivateCGCompositePlusLighter  = 12, // (min (1, s + d))
};
void CGContextSetCompositeOperation (CGContextRef, PrivateCGCompositeMode);



@interface NSWindow (AppKitPrivate)
+ (Class)frameViewClassForStyleMask:(NSInteger)styleMask;
- (BOOL)_usesCustomDrawing;
@end

@interface NSThemeFrame : NSView
- (void)shapeWindow;
-(void)drawOverlayRect:(CGRect) arg2;
- (void)_maskCorners:(NSUInteger)aFlags clipRect:(NSRect)aRect;

- (void)_setContentView:(id)view;
- (void)_getWindowMaskCornerDimensionsLeftCornerWidth:(double*)l rightCornerWidth:(double*)r topCornerHeight: (double*)t bottomCornerHeight: (double*) b;
@end

#pragma mark Core Graphics

// these are private Core Graphics calls we use to blur the window's background
typedef void * CGSConnection;
extern CGError CGSSetWindowBackgroundBlurRadius(CGSConnection connection, NSInteger windowNumber, int radius);
extern CGSConnection CGSDefaultConnectionForThread();



@class GRGlassWindowFrame;

@interface GRGlassWindow : NSWindow

// an accessory view placed on the right hand side of the window,
// this can be used to put a button or other view,
// if you want to put more than one button you can
// make a view with the buttons inside and use
// the view as the accessory view
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSView *accessoryView;

// this makes the titlebar fade out when the mouse leaves the window
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hidesTitleBar;

// smaller text below the title
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end



@interface GRGlassWindowFrame : NSThemeFrame

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hidesTitleBar;

@property (nonatomic) NSView *contentView;

@end

@interface GRGlassWindow ()

@property (nonatomic, readonly) GRGlassWindowFrame *frameView;

@end

@implementation GRGlassWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:aStyle backing:bufferingType defer:flag];
    if(!self) return nil;
    [self setOpaque: YES];
    return self;
}

#define kGRGlassWindowTitleBarHeight 20

// returns the correct rect for the title bar window
- (NSRect)titleWindowRect
{
    return NSMakeRect(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y+NSHeight(self.frame)-kGRGlassWindowTitleBarHeight-0.5, NSWidth(self.frame), kGRGlassWindowTitleBarHeight);
}

// this tells appkit we want the window's frame to be a GRGlassWindowFrame
+ (Class)frameViewClassForStyleMask:(NSInteger)styleMask
{
    return [GRGlassWindowFrame class];
}

// this makes our custom window frame have the correct appearance and shadow
- (BOOL)_usesCustomDrawing
{
    return NO;
}



- (GRGlassWindowFrame *)frameView
{
    return (GRGlassWindowFrame *)[self.contentView superview];
}

- (void) setContentView: (NSView *) view {
    if (![self frameView]) {
        [super setContentView: view];
    } else {
        [view setFrame:[self frameView].frame];
        [[self frameView] setContentView: view];
    }


}


@end


//typedef CFTypeRef CUIRendererRef;
//extern void (*CUIDraw)(CUIRendererRef renderer, CGRect frame, CGContextRef context, CFDictionaryRef options, CFDictionaryRef *result);


// this is the window frame, responsible for it's look
@implementation GRGlassWindowFrame
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{

    
//  CGImageRef img = CUISharedArtReaderCreateImage(1.0, CUIGetImageIDForMapID(0x4e56));

//  CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationIn);
//  CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 11, 11), img);
//  CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeSourceOver);     
    if ([self contentView] != nil) {
        [_contentView drawRect:dirtyRect];
    }
    [self _maskCorners:-1 clipRect:dirtyRect];
}

- (void) setContentView: (NSView *) view {
    _contentView = view;
}


- (void)_maskCorners:(NSUInteger)aFlags clipRect:(NSRect)aRect {
    
//    
//    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
//    CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationIn);
//    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
//    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 900));
    
//    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3f] set];
//    printf("%f\n", CGRectGetHeight([self frame]));
//    NSRectFillUsingOperation([self frame], NSCompositeCopy);
    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationIn);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, [self frame].size.height - 20, 20, 20));
    CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeSourceOver);
//  [super _maskCorners: -1 clipRect: NSZeroRect];
}

// this makes the content view flush with the window's top
+ (double)_titlebarHeight:(unsigned long long)arg1
{
    return 50;
}
- (BOOL)topCornerRounded
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL) bottomCornerRounded {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)_wantsTitleBar
{
    return NO;
}
-(float) roundedCornerRadius {
    return 30;
}




@end

@interface MyNsView : NSView
@end

@implementation MyNsView
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeCopy);

}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [app setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

        GRGlassWindow *window = [[GRGlassWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
            styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask
            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
            defer:NO];
//      [window setBackingType:NSBackingStoreBuffered]; // new backing store is type 3, unbuffered
        [window setShowsResizeIndicator:YES];
        
        [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
        [window setOpaque:YES];
        window.contentView = [[MyNsView alloc] init];

        [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
        [app run];

    }
}
```

But what about OpenGLViews? If you try the same trick there, we run out of luck because no matter how hard we try the OpenGL surface always seems to clobber what's below it, particularly the top corners. How do the bottom corners manage to escape this? It turns out it's because when the OpenGL surface is created, there's a method on `NSSurface` that takes care of creating a "clipped" surface. By default it always uses region encompassing the bottom of the surface, so only the bottom corners get the clip treatment. (You can actually see an artifact of this if you zoom closely, e.g. using color meter and take a look at the corner of a window with opengl content. If you draw something bright, the corner doesn't quite have a natural fade with alpha like usual corners, it's a jagged pixel clip and only behind that lies the usual corner mask drawn by quartz). With a bit of ingenuity we can swizzle this method to return a mask for both top and bottom corners, and with that we get (for the first documented time as far as I'm aware) a full-content OpenGLView *with* rounded corners (unfortunately you can't draw directly on top of it, so the best option performance-wise is probably layering a small transparent nswindow on top just for the controls, and you can hide/show that at will. See this [project](https://github.com/insidegui/GRGlassWindow) for such an example. )

```
enum PrivateCGCompositeMode {
    kPrivateCGCompositeClear        = 0,
    kPrivateCGCompositeCopy     = 1,
    kPrivateCGCompositeSourceOver   = 2,
    kPrivateCGCompositeSourceIn     = 3,
    kPrivateCGCompositeSourceOut    = 4,
    kPrivateCGCompositeSourceAtop   = 5,
    kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationOver  = 6,
    kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationIn    = 7,
    kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationOut   = 8,
    kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationAtop  = 9,
    kPrivateCGCompositeXOR      = 10,
    kPrivateCGCompositePlusDarker   = 11, // (max (0, (1-d) + (1-s)))
    kPrivateCGCompositePlusLighter  = 12, // (min (1, s + d))
};
void CGContextSetCompositeOperation (CGContextRef, PrivateCGCompositeMode);



@interface NSWindow (AppKitPrivate)
+ (Class)frameViewClassForStyleMask:(NSInteger)styleMask;
- (BOOL)_usesCustomDrawing;
@end

@interface NSThemeFrame : NSView
- (void)shapeWindow;
-(void)drawOverlayRect:(CGRect) arg2;
- (void)_maskCorners:(NSUInteger)aFlags clipRect:(NSRect)aRect;
- (float) roundedCornerRadius;
- (void)_setContentView:(id)view;
- (void)_getWindowMaskCornerDimensionsLeftCornerWidth:(double*)l rightCornerWidth:(double*)r topCornerHeight: (double*)t bottomCornerHeight: (double*) b;
@end

#pragma mark Core Graphics

// these are private Core Graphics calls we use to blur the window's background
typedef void * CGSConnection;
extern CGError CGSSetWindowBackgroundBlurRadius(CGSConnection connection, NSInteger windowNumber, int radius);
extern CGSConnection CGSDefaultConnectionForThread();



@class GRGlassWindowFrame;

@interface GRGlassWindow : NSWindow

// an accessory view placed on the right hand side of the window,
// this can be used to put a button or other view,
// if you want to put more than one button you can
// make a view with the buttons inside and use
// the view as the accessory view
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSView *accessoryView;

// this makes the titlebar fade out when the mouse leaves the window
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hidesTitleBar;

// smaller text below the title
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end



@interface GRGlassWindowFrame : NSThemeFrame

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hidesTitleBar;

@property (nonatomic) NSView *contentView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOpenGLContext *openGLContext;

@end

@interface GRGlassWindow ()

@property (nonatomic, readonly) GRGlassWindowFrame *frameView;

@end

@implementation GRGlassWindow

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:aStyle backing:bufferingType defer:flag];
    if(!self) return nil;
    [self setOpaque: YES];
    return self;
}

#define kGRGlassWindowTitleBarHeight 20

// returns the correct rect for the title bar window
- (NSRect)titleWindowRect
{
    return NSMakeRect(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y+NSHeight(self.frame)-kGRGlassWindowTitleBarHeight-0.5, NSWidth(self.frame), kGRGlassWindowTitleBarHeight);
}

// this tells appkit we want the window's frame to be a GRGlassWindowFrame
+ (Class)frameViewClassForStyleMask:(NSInteger)styleMask
{
    return [GRGlassWindowFrame class];
}

// this makes our custom window frame have the correct appearance and shadow
- (BOOL)_usesCustomDrawing
{
    return NO;
}



- (GRGlassWindowFrame *)frameView
{
    return (GRGlassWindowFrame *)[self.contentView superview];
}

- (void) setContentView: (NSView *) view {
    if (![self frameView]) {
        [super setContentView: view];
    } else {
        [view setFrame:[self frameView].frame];
        [[self frameView] setContentView: view];
    }


}


@end


//typedef CFTypeRef CUIRendererRef;
//extern void (*CUIDraw)(CUIRendererRef renderer, CGRect frame, CGContextRef context, CFDictionaryRef options, CFDictionaryRef *result);


// this is the window frame, responsible for it's look
@implementation GRGlassWindowFrame
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{

    
//  CGImageRef img = CUISharedArtReaderCreateImage(1.0, CUIGetImageIDForMapID(0x4e56));

//  CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationIn);
//  CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 11, 11), img);
//  CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeSourceOver);     
    if ([self contentView] == nil) {
        return;
    }
    [[self contentView] drawRect: dirtyRect];
//  
    [self _maskCorners:-1 clipRect:dirtyRect];
}

- (void)_maskCorners:(NSUInteger)aFlags clipRect:(NSRect)aRect {
    
//    
//    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
//    CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationIn);
//    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
//    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 900));
    
//    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1.0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3f] set];
//    printf("%f\n", CGRectGetHeight([self frame]));
//    NSRectFillUsingOperation([self frame], NSCompositeCopy);
    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeDestinationIn);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20));
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, [self frame].size.height - 20, 20, 20));
    CGContextSetCompositeOperation(context, kPrivateCGCompositeSourceOver);
//  [super _maskCorners: -1 clipRect: NSZeroRect];
}
+ (double)_titlebarHeight:(unsigned long long)arg1
{
    return 50;
}
- (BOOL)topCornerRounded
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL) bottomCornerRounded {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)_wantsTitleBar
{
    return NO;
}
-(float) roundedCornerRadius {
    return 4;
}

-(BOOL) _shouldRoundCornersForSurface{
    return true;
}



- (void) setContentView: (NSView *) view {
    
    _contentView = view;
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect([self frame]));

    // Create an NSOpenGLPixelFormat object with double buffering enabled
    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[] = {
        NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
        0
    };
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attribs];
    
    // Create an NSOpenGLContext object with the pixel format
    NSOpenGLContext *glContext = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pixelFormat shareContext:nil];
    self.openGLContext = glContext;
 
    [[self openGLContext] setView: self];
    [[self openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
    
}




@end

@interface MyNsView : NSView
@end

@implementation MyNsView
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {   
//  [[NSColor blueColor] set];
//  NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeCopy);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glFlush();
//  [[NSColor blueColor] set];
//  NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeCopy);
}
@end

CG_EXTERN CGError CGSNewRegionWithRectList(const CGRect *rects, int rectCount, CFTypeRef *outRegion);


@interface NSSurface : NSObject
- (struct CGSRegionObject * ) _createRoundedBottomRegionForRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end

hook(NSSurface)


- (struct CGSRegionObject * ) _createRoundedBottomRegionForRect:(CGRect)rect {
    /**
    CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 448),
                          CGRectMake(1, 448, 398, 1),
                          CGRectMake(2, 449, 396, 1),
                        */
    struct CGSRegionObject * parent = _orig(struct CGSRegionObject *, rect);
    CGRect rects[] = {CGRectMake(0, 227, 400, 221),
                      CGRectMake(1, 448, 398, 1),
                      CGRectMake(2, 449, 396, 1),
                    
                      CGRectMake(2, 0, 400, 1),
                      CGRectMake(1, 1, 398, 1),
                      CGRectMake(0, 2, 400, 225)};
    
    struct CGSRegionObject *out;
    CGSNewRegionWithRectList(rects, 6, &out);
                    
    NSLog(@"%@", parent);
    NSLog(@"%@", out);
    return out;
}
endhook

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
        [app setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];

        GRGlassWindow *window = [[GRGlassWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
            styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask
            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
            defer:NO];
//      [window setBackingType:NSBackingStoreBuffered]; // new backing store is type 3, unbuffered
        [window setShowsResizeIndicator:YES];
        
        [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
        [window setOpaque:YES];
        
    
        window.contentView = [[MyNsView alloc] init];

        [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
        [app run];

    }
}
```

Finally if you want to make your corners look like the official thing, you can re-use Apple's existing corner mask, via `CUIGetImageIDForMapID` with IDs I mentioned in the other linked post. See the commented out sections of the code. (Note these functions are not exported so they can't be linked as usual, you'll have to do some shenanigans to get the function pointer directly from the loaded dylib).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the setAlphaValue method of NSWindow.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work because it applies transparency even to all the views hosted by the window